# Wordpress ACF Repeater - click link to Display the content of a single row

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using the Wordpress ACF PRO plugin Repeater Field to build a product catalog.

I need each product to have a link that will display the information as a single page.

When the link for the product is clicked the else function kicks in but the products still display as a list.

I thought of using the counter $i as an ID to specify the product I want to link to and open a single product page but have no idea of how to do this.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Here's an image of what I want [how the catalogue should work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94pgL.png)

And this is what I get at the moment whichever link is clicked all of the products get listed [How Catalogue works at the moment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZE36u.jpg)

Here's my code.

```html
<!-- DISPLAY PRODUCT LIST -->

<?php 
  if (!isset($_GET['product'])) { ?>
    <?php if( have_rows('product') ): $i = 0; ?>
      <?php while( have_rows('product') ): the_row(); $i++; ?>

        <h1>PRODUCT LIST - <?php echo $i; ?></h1>

        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>?product=<?php $slug = urlencode(the_sub_field('product_name')); ?>">View Product</a>
     <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; 
?>

 <?php } else { 

<!-- DISPLAY SINGLE PRODUCT -->

  if( have_rows('product') ): $i = 0;
    while( have_rows('product') ): the_row(); $i++; 
   
    $single_product = get_row('$i');
      ?>
    
  <h1><?php> echo $single_product['product_name']; ?> - <?php echo $i; ?></h1>
   <?php echo $single_product['price']; echo "<br />";?>

    <?php endwhile;
    endif; 
  }
?>
```

Comment: Post a picture of what you're getting vs what you want. Screenshot & a simple paint sketch should do the trick.

Comment: Have you considered instead creating each product as its own page? You can have friendly URLs that way, and URLs/content won't become unsynced just because you decide you want to re-order the list or delete a product. Then get your link via a field of type `Page Link`

Comment: your escaped your '$i' in the get_row - so in my mind - it will look for a row with the id of '$i' and not something like '5'?

Comment: @ProViz Images uploaded.

Comment: @scoots Thought about that but I'm trying to create an intuitive interface for a client who doesn't "do computers". :-)

Comment: @Stender Yup that's the issue. At the moment the links are returning all items '$i'. I cant work out how to define each link to a specific id.